# How to get hidden field value to make dynamic id, class, value of a input type

Tags: jsp

I want name, class, value, id of input type to be updated by hidden field named 'productCodeComp' in below comment as I able to post it. I don't know why.

```
<input type="hidden" id="productCodeComp" name="productCodeComp" value="${productId}" />
<div class="product-item-compare"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="item-" class="productCompare" name="item-" value="" onclick="productCompare('')"/> 
<label for="item-">Compare</label> 
</div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="productCodeComp" name="productCodeComp" value="${productId}" />
   <div class="product-item-compare">
    <input type="checkbox" id="item-"
     class="productCompare" name="item-"
     value="" onclick="productCompare('')"/> 
    <label for="item-">Compare</label>
   </div>

Comment: could you provide exact question?